# how reset index with respect of a group?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have an `id` column for each person (data with the same id belongs to one person). I want these:

1. Now the `id` column is not based on numbering, it's 10 digit. How can I reset `id` with integers, e.g. *1, 2, 3, 4*?

For example:

```
id     col1
12a4   summer
12a4   goest
3b     yes
3b     No
3b     why
4t     Hi
```

Output:

```
id   col1
1    summer
1    goest
2    yes
2    No
2    why
3    Hi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use, `factorize`:

```
df['id']=df['id'].factorize()[0]+1
```

Output:

```
   id    col1
0   1  summer
1   1   goest
2   2     yes
3   2      No
4   2     why
5   3      Hi
```

Another option is to use categorical data:

```
df['id'] = df['id'].astype('category').cat.codes + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([('bird', 389.0),
                   ('bird', 24.0),
                   ('mammal', 80.5),
                   ('mammal', np.nan)],
                  index=['falcon', 'parrot', 'lion', 'monkey'],
                  columns=('class', 'max_speed'))
print(df)
         class  max_speed
falcon    bird      389.0
parrot    bird       24.0
lion    mammal       80.5
monkey  mammal        NaN
```

This is how looks like, let replace the index:

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
print(df)
    index   class  max_speed
0  falcon    bird      389.0
1  parrot    bird       24.0
2    lion  mammal       80.5
3  monkey  mammal        NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['12a4', '12a4', '3b', '3b', '3b', '4t'],
                   'col1': ['summer', 'goest', 'yes', 'No', 'why', 'Hi']})

unique_id = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['id']).reset_index(drop=True)

id_dict = dict(zip(unique_id['id'], unique_id.index))

df['id'] = df['id'].apply(lambda x: id_dict[x])
```

`df.drop_duplicates(subset=['id']).reset_index(drop=True)` removes duplicate rows in column `id`.

```
# print(unique_id)
     id    col1
0  12a4  summer
1    3b     yes
2    4t      Hi
```

`dict(zip(unique_id['id'], unique_id.index))` creates a dictionary from column `id` and index value.

```py
# print(id_dict)

{'12a4': 0, '3b': 1, '4t': 2}
```

`df['id'].apply(lambda x: id_dict[x])` sets the column value mapping with value from dict.

```
# print(df)

   id    col1
0   0  summer
1   0   goest
2   1     yes
3   1      No
4   1     why
5   2      Hi
```